# How to make naive bayes multinomial with TF-idf from scratch in python?

Tags: python, naivebayes, multinomial

I know there is a library in python

> from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

but I want to know how to create one from scratch without using libraries like TfIdfVectorizer and MultinomialNB?

Comment: Welcome to SO fik! Do you mean "*how do I implement Naive Bayes + how do I implement a TFIDF vectorizer*" or "*after importing the library, how do I fit the model to data?*"

Comment: how do I implement Naive Bayes with TFIDF without using the library TfIdfVectorizer and MultinomialNB(), but from scratch

Comment: The question is too broad to answer here, please review [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For an overview of multinomial naive Bayes, [Dan Jurafsky's slides (slide 41 specifically)](http://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/slides/7_NB.pdf#page=41) has a worked example, and [Gautam Kunapuli's slides are a good reference](https://gkunapuli.github.io/files/cs6375/09-NaiveBayes.pdf). Both explain naive Bayes with respect to the bag of words (`CountVectorizer`) model, but their implementation would be equivalent for a TFIDF vectorizer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step-by-step about how to make simple MNB Classifier with TF-IDF

1. First, you need to import the method **TfIdfVectorizer** to tokenize the terms inside the dataset, the **MultinomialNB** as the classifier, and the **train_test_split** for splitting the dataset. (Both are available in sklearn).
2. Split the dataset into **train** and **test** sets.
3. Initialize the constructor of **TfIdfVectorizer**, then Vectorize/Tokenize the **train set** by the method **fit_transform**.
4. Vectorize/Fit the **test set** with the method **fit**.
5. Initialize the classifier by calling the constructor **MultinomialNB()**.

```py
model = MultinomialNB() # with default hyperparameters
```

6. Train the classifier with the **train set**.

```py
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

7. Test/Validate the classifier with the **test set**.

```py
model.predict(X_test, y_test)
```

Those 7 steps above are the simple steps. Apparently you can also do the **text preprocessing** and also model **evaluation**.

Comment: I don't mean using libraries like TfIdfVectorizer and MultinomialNB(), but how to build them from scratch